# Listview not refreshing deleted row from data base

Tags: java, android, database, listview

I have a database of addresses. I just want the user to be able to delete a row but the list wont update.  I have seen all the other people's examples but they are not working for me. I keep trying variations of different things. They all produce no effect. I have to change activities and then it deletes.

I add the address in one activity  and end it with a finish();

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    db.addAddress(str);

    Intent intent= new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();

}
```

Here is my deleteAddress() for  mylistview and i use it in on resume.

```
 private void deleteAddress(){
    listview= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            final String selectedID = String.valueOf(position);
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(Address.this);
            adb.setTitle("Delete?");
            adb.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete?");
            final int positionToRemove = position;
            adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dbHelper.deleteAddress(selectedID);
                    updateList();

                }});
            adb.show();
            return true;
        }

    });
}
public void updateList(){
   dbHelper.fetchAllAddresses();
   dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here is my deleteAddress in database

```
public void deleteAddress(String rowId) {
    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // 2. delete
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, //table name
            "_id"+"=?",  // selections
            new String[] {rowId}); //selections args
    // 3. close
    db.close();
```

}

here is my listview

```
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    deleteAddress();
    cursor= dbHelper.fetchAllAddresses();
    String columns[]= new String[]{
            dbHelper.KEY_NAME

    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.rowTextView,
    };
    dataAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,R.layout.simplerow, cursor,columns,to,0);
    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listview= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Where setting  Adapter for ListView?

Comment: i added my listview@ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 1):

you are using `position` as row id, in your `deleteAddress` method, but you should `id`, parameter of `onItemClick` instead. Change

```
final String selectedID = String.valueOf(position);
```

with

```
final String selectedID = String.valueOf(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

How looks your adapter? You need to delete the item in the adapters-item-list, not just in the database... Do that and then call notifyDataSetChanged()!

Answer (score 0):

I am not correcting your code as there is a lot can fix, just providing your answer in your way, try this

```
public void updateList(){

cursor= dbHelper.fetchAllAddresses();
    String columns[]= new String[]{
            dbHelper.KEY_NAME

    };
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.rowTextView,
    };
    dataAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,R.layout.simplerow, cursor,columns,to,0);
listview.setAdapter(dataAdapter); 
}
```

Comment: it didnt work. i already tried that before. i dont understand why.